# How to crosscut annotated methods and constructors?

Tags: java, constructor, aop, aspectj

This is what I'm doing:

```
@Aspect
public class MethodLogger {
  @Around("(execution(* *(..)) || initialization(*.new(..))) && @annotation(Foo)")
  public Object wrap(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    // works fine, but only for methods
  }
}
```

The snippet works fine, but only for method calls. This is what [AspectJ maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) is saying after applying the aspect (not during its compilation, which works just fine):

```
around on initialization not supported (compiler limitation)
```

Any workaround? I'm with OpenJDK 7:

```
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Could you tell me please why do you need _around_ advice on object construction? Why not to write just _after_ advice?

Comment: I want to measure how much time it takes to run the ctor (or method)

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to technical limitations there is no such thing as `around()` advice on `initialization()` or `preinitialization()` pointcuts. And there is another problem in the chronological order of when the corresponding joinpoints are being entered and exited. Look at this example:

```java
public abstract class ApplicationBase {
    private int id = 0;

    public ApplicationBase(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Application extends ApplicationBase {
    private String name = "<unnamed>";

    public Application(int id, String name) {
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application(1, "Foo");
        new Application(2, "Bar");
    }
}
```

```java
public aspect ExecutionTimingAspect {
    private String indentText = "";

    pointcut constructorCall() :
        call(*Application*.new(..));

    pointcut constructorRelated() :
        constructorCall() ||
        initialization(*Application*.new(..)) ||
        preinitialization(*Application*.new(..)) ||
        execution(*Application*.new(..));

    after() : constructorRelated() {
        indentText = indentText.substring(2);
        System.out.println(indentText + "<< " + thisJoinPointStaticPart);
    }

    before() : constructorRelated() {
        System.out.println(indentText + ">> " + thisJoinPointStaticPart);
        indentText += "  ";
    }

    Object around() : constructorCall() {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Object result = proceed();
        System.out.println(indentText + "Constructor runtime = " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1.0e9 + " s\n");
        return result;
    }
}
```

You will see the following output:

```
>> call(Application(int, String))
  >> preinitialization(Application(int, String))
  << preinitialization(Application(int, String))
  >> preinitialization(ApplicationBase(int))
  << preinitialization(ApplicationBase(int))
  >> initialization(ApplicationBase(int))
    >> execution(ApplicationBase(int))
    << execution(ApplicationBase(int))
  << initialization(ApplicationBase(int))
  >> initialization(Application(int, String))
    >> execution(Application(int, String))
    << execution(Application(int, String))
  << initialization(Application(int, String))
<< call(Application(int, String))
Constructor runtime = 0.00123172 s

>> call(Application(int, String))
  >> preinitialization(Application(int, String))
  << preinitialization(Application(int, String))
  >> preinitialization(ApplicationBase(int))
  << preinitialization(ApplicationBase(int))
  >> initialization(ApplicationBase(int))
    >> execution(ApplicationBase(int))
    << execution(ApplicationBase(int))
  << initialization(ApplicationBase(int))
  >> initialization(Application(int, String))
    >> execution(Application(int, String))
    << execution(Application(int, String))
  << initialization(Application(int, String))
<< call(Application(int, String))
Constructor runtime = 0.00103393 s
```

Can you see how preinitialisation of the derived class starts and finishes before preinitialisation of its base class? And how initialisation works just the other way around, but as an additional complication constructor execution is embedded in initialisation?

Maybe now you understand that just measuring initialisation, even if it was possible via `around()`, would not reflect the constructor's overall execution time. So if you are lucky enough to be able to intercept constructor `call()` instead of `execution()` because you have access to the calling code, you are fine and can even use `around()` as I did in my example (which is, by the way, not thread-safe, but I tried to keep it simple). If you cannot influence the caller, but can only weave the callee, you need to use other tricks, such as aspect-internal bookkeeping of when preinitialisation of a certain constructor is entered via `before()` and then when initialisation of the same constructor call is exited via `after()`. I.e. you need to keep some internal state in between advice executions. This is possible, but a little more complicated. If you want to discuss this further, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround - you can introduce factory for such needs to apply around advice on its methods.