# How do I capture object initialization time using AspectJ?

Tags: java, initialization, aop, aspectj

If I need to trace the time at which the object is created, using AspectJ, do I capture a call to the constructor, a constructor executing or a object initialisation? All three have different syntaxes: `pointcut: call`, `pointcut: execution` and `pointcut: initialization`, respectively.

What is the difference between all three and which one would be perfect to use?

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer or Andrew's one if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These 3 pointcuts are overlapping, but have different semantics.  From the [AspectJ programming guide](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/quick.html):

1. Call pointcut: The invocation of a constructor call (ie- a call to new Foo()).  The currently executing object (ie- this) is not the object being created, but the object calling new.
2. Execution pointcut: From the first line of a constructor until it returns. The this object is the thing being created (and may not exist yet for before and around advice).
3. Initialization pointcut: like execution pointcut, but does not include the call to super constructors.

Since I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, I can't advise which would make the most sense, but if you are trying to find out how much time it takes to create an object, then using the execution pointcut makes the most sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to log the time at which the object is created, not the time it takes to be created. I've tried 'execution' and 'initialization', and didn't see the difference. And even 'after' or 'before' doesn't change the result I get.

Comment: What does creation time mean?  Is it when memory is first allocated, or when the constructor completes?  Execution and initialization are similar. Only difference is whether or not super constructors are taken into account. And how are you getting the time?  System.currentTimeMillis()? I'd expect that not to register any difference for individual constructor calls since they would take much less than 1ms to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question here: [How to crosscut annotated methods and constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642646/how-to-crosscut-annotated-methods-and-constructors/15571384#15571384)

Maybe this helps clarify what Andrew has already pointed out. The answer contains a little code sample with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To better understand join points, which your pointcut will address, this simple example could help you:

```
class C {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}

public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
        c.foo();
    }
}
```

Now let's have an aspect that will print all possible join points alterable with *before* and *after* advices:

```
public aspect MyAspect {

    pointcut Anything() : 
        cflow(!within(MyAspect)) && !within(MyAspect);

    before() : Anything() {
        System.out.println("before " + thisJoinPoint);
    }

    after() : Anything() {
        System.out.println("after " + thisJoinPoint);
    }

}
```

which yields the following output:

```
...
before call(C())                           // <-- call to constructor, new C()
before staticinitialization(C.<clinit>)
after staticinitialization(C.<clinit>)
before preinitialization(C())
after preinitialization(C())
before initialization(C())
before execution(C())                      // <-- actual execution of constructor
after execution(C())
after initialization(C())
after call(C())                            // <-- after call to constructor
...
```

So if you look at the time of initialization of an object as a time since the moment the constructor is called until the moment the execution comes back to the same scope where it was called, this might be a way to go:

```
public aspect ConstructionTiming {

    private long startTime, endTime;

    before() : call(C.new(..)) {
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
    after() : call(C.new(..)) {
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("construction took " +
                            (endTime - startTime)/1e6 + "ms");
    }
}
```

which in my case outputted `construction took 0.64879ms`