# AspectJ: track new object initialization

Tags: java, object, initialization, aspectj

I'm trying to understand AspectJ. I want to try to count all object initializations (which are initialized from the classes I've specified, not some Java-internal ones) in a project and I'm really not sure how to do this.

Let's say I have classes called A and B, where A has subclasses Aa and Ab, B has the subclasses Ba and Bb, and Bb has the subclass Bba. I'd like my aspect to track every single initialization of the objects created with those classes as a base, but I don't really understand how to properly do this (even though this should be somewhat simple). So far, I have something similar to this:

```
public aspect AspectCounter {
        private int objects = 0;

        pointcut countObjects() : initialization(A.new(..)) || initialization(B.new(..));

        pointcut printObjects() : call(* Test.printCounter(..));

        after() : countObjects() {
            objects++;
        }

        after() : printObjects() {
            System.out.println(objects);
        }
}
```

Which does, at least, print the right amount of A's and B's I've created (I didn't go with B*.new(..) since it would, the way I understand it, track any initialization of Bba three times which I don't want in this case).
The way it works right now is that I have a Test class which, well, does test stuff, and after I'm done with the testing, I'm just calling an empty printCounter method that doesn't really do anything. It seems to work and does actually give me the right number of objects, but I'm sure there's a better way to do this. I really don't like having an empty method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with `initialization`, `preinitialization` or `execution` pointcuts on `*.new(..)` because of the order in which they are executed. They are not nested as you might think but executed rather sequentially due to the way the JVM works. I have explained this in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15571384/1082681) including sample code and log output. So you are only left with the option to use a `call` pointcut. Here is an example:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class A {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Aa extends A {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Ab extends A {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class B {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Ba extends B {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Bb extends B {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Bba extends Bb {}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A();
        new Aa();
        new Ab();
        new B();
        new Ba();
        new Bb();
        new Bba();
    }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.A;
import de.scrum_master.app.B;

public aspect InstanceCreationCounter {
    private static int count;

    after() : call(A+.new(..)) || call(B+.new(..)) {
        System.out.printf("%4d %s%n", ++count, thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
   1 call(de.scrum_master.app.A())
   2 call(de.scrum_master.app.Aa())
   3 call(de.scrum_master.app.Ab())
   4 call(de.scrum_master.app.B())
   5 call(de.scrum_master.app.Ba())
   6 call(de.scrum_master.app.Bb())
   7 call(de.scrum_master.app.Bba())
```

I guess this is what you want.

**Caveat:** You need to have control over all the calling code and weave the aspect into it in order for this to work.